# Is the second law of thermodynamics a real law?

Tags: thermodynamics, soft-question, entropy

Everytime I ask people why the second law of thermodynamics is true, they say because the probability of entropy increasing is very large. This for some reason doesn't seem right for me. Just because something has a high probability of happening doesn't mean that it is a fundamental law of nature.

Can someone say that because it is very unlikely to win the lottery that it is a LAW that you won't win?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the second law of thermodynamics a fundamental law, or does it emerge from other laws?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96081/)