# Example of Poincare recurrence theorem?

Tags: astronomy, climate-science, poincare-recurrence

Is it possible to explain Milankovitch cycles (or some other arbitrary planetary configuration that recurs to some approximation) in terms of the Poincare recurrence theorem?

> More generally, is there a good physical example of the Poincare recurrence theorem?

Comment: I realize that a pendulum would work. I'm interested in situations that are more or less ergonomic.

Comment: Edited to make this more answerable. I think maybe Ehrenfest's idea is a candidate , and even allows a calculation of return times. See http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/magic/lecture05.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just had a pedagogical paper on Poincare recurrence:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01444

Yes, for the planetary configuration problem, some of the recurrences can be predicted accurately. It reduces to a classic problem in number theory, namely, the simultaneous Diophantine approximation problem for real numbers. Mathematicians have done a lot on this problem and in particular, a famous algorithm (the LLL algorithm) exists.

Comment: This is a nice example. I have to study a little more before accepting this answer but it's a good physical example. I learned a bit about Mathematica too!

Comment: The paper cited effectively provides a mathematical refutation of the claim by Laura Mersini-Houghton, made on p.164 in the 2012 ed. of the book titled "The Arrows of Time:  A Debate in Cosmology", that "Poincare recurrences do not occur".